# Что означает такой typedef?

Tags: c, winapi, функции, указатели, typedef

Я не могу понять этот typedef и что там делает макрос WINAPI(stdcall)

```
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);
```

В дальнейшем было описано следующее:

```
LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process;

void x_32_64(list <info> &gqlist)
{
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;

    //IsWow64Process is not available on all supported versions of Windows.
    //Use GetModuleHandle to get a handle to the DLL that contains the function
    //and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the function if available.

    fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "IsWow64Process");
    list <info> ::iterator it;
    for (it = gqlist.begin(); it != gqlist.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (NULL != fnIsWow64Process)
        {
            if (!fnIsWow64Process(OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, it->num_PID), &bIsWow64))
            {
                it->x_bit = 9;
            }
        }
     ///////////
     }
```

Не понятно, что происходит тут:

```
fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "IsWow64Process");
```

И почему `fnIsWow64Process` начала вести себя как функция?

Comment: [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) определяет синоним типа. А `fnIsWow64Process` начинает вести себя как функция потому, что содержит адрес функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вообще такое `typedef`. Грубо говоря, из объявления переменной это слово делает объявление типа.

```
int A;          // Объявление переменной A
typedef int A;  // Объявление ТИПА A как int
```

Объявим функцию - `LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS`, от `HANDLE` и `PBOOL`, с соглашением о передаче аргументов `WINAPI` и возвращаемым значением `BOOL`:

```
BOOL WINAPI LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS(HANDLE, PBOOL);
```

Как объявляется указатель на что-то? приписывается `*`.

```
int a;        // Переменная типа int
int *a;       // a - указатель на int
```

Значит, сделать `LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS` указателем на ту страшную функцию можно так:

```
BOOL WINAPI (*LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)(HANDLE, PBOOL);
```

Скобки нужны, чтоб компилятор разобрался, к чему относится `*`.

А `typedef`  делает из `LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS` не указатель на такую вот функцию, а *тип* указателя на нее.

```
typedef BOOL WINAPI (*LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)(HANDLE, PBOOL);
```

Т.е. теперь это `LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS` можно использовать как имя типа.

```
LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process;
```

Т.е. теперь `fnIsWow64Process` - указатель на такую страшную, описанную выше функцию.

Все. Осталось присвоить ей значение и работать, как с обычной функцией - потому что имя функции и указатель на нее взаимозаменяемы.

P.S. Почему при такой полной взаимозаменяемости нужно использовать именно указатель, а не просто имя в `typedef` - ну, как

```
typedef BOOL WINAPI LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS(HANDLE, PBOOL);
```

это уж пусть гуру в стандартах пояснят...

Comment: _Значит, сделать LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS указателем на ту страшную функцию можно так_ , а почему мы не поставили звёздочку на BOOL ? А поставили на имя функции?

Comment: Потому, что именно имя представляет собой указатель. `int * f()` - функция `f`, возвращающая `int*`, а `int (*f)()` - указатель на функцию, возвращающую `int`.